# Getting the following error when clicking on Login button with webdriver: Request failed due to element click intercepted

Tags: webdriver-io

When clicking on the login button using below XPATH getting following error: Request failed due to element click intercepted, see below image of HTML code:

XPATH:

('//*[@id="btnLogin"]');

('//a[@id="btnLogin"]');

('#btnLogin');

('//a[@id="btnLogin"]/text()');

('//a[contains(@id, "btnLogin")]');

('//a[@id="btnLogin" and @class = "big-button lnkbuttonlogin"]');

[image: Request failed due to element click intercepted]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//*[@id='btnLogin']

//a[@id='btnLogin']

Above locators should work , press F12 . go to elements tab 
.Type ctrl +F and search for matching nodes using above locators .

Alternatively , Try clicking using a Javascript .
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

```
String idloc="btnLogin";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('"+idloc+"').click();");
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Yes you are correct that above locators should work, but the locators highlighting not just id but everything in html page as it can be seen from image. I am using Node.js and Webdriver IO with javascript.  It does not work for me in Chrome browser using those locators. For Javascript to work what Node.js package I need to import? The import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor; is not being recognized.

Comment: @AriN to click with js simply use browser.execute command. 
 browser.execute("arguments[0].click();", yourElementHere). Where yourElementHere is your element locator or reference to it(duh)

Comment: Problem solved!  Thank you so much Yuriy! You made my date. The only thing I had to change was instead of double quotes use single ones.